# Opencart Login custom api with mysqli prepare

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart

I'm making some login api functions with mysqli prepare etc.

The proper login function that open cart is using, is the following

```
$customer_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE LOWER(email) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($email)) . "' AND (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "'))))) OR password = '" . $this->db->escape(md5($password)) . "') AND status = '1' AND approved = '1'");
```

And i'm trying to make it with mysqli prepare statement with the following code.

```
$result = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT customer_id, firstname, lastname, email, telephone, fax, address_id, customer_group_id FROM `oa_customer` WHERE LOWER(email) = ? AND password = ? OR password = ? ;");

$md5pass = md5($password);
$newpass = "SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $password . "'))))"
                echo "md5 ";
                print_r($md5pass);
                echo "new ";
                print_r($newpass);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, 'sss', utf8_strtolower($email), $password, $md5pass);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $customerid, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone, $fax, $address_id, $coustomer_group_id);

                while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result))
                  {     
                        $id = $customerid;
                        $name = $firstname;
                        $surname = $lastname;
                        $email = $email;
                        $phone = $telephone;
                        $fax = $fax;
                        $addressid = $address_id;
                        $customergroup = $customer_group_id;

                  }
                mysqli_stmt_close($result);
                mysqli_close($db);
```

My only problem is this line

```
$newpass = "SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $password . "'))))"
```

Which is trying to represent the following code of the first original login query

```
(password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "')))))
```

While i'm trying this i get error 500 on the request.

Second try was the following.

Instead of using

```
$newpass = "SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "'))))"
```

I replaced it with

```
$newpass = sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($password)));
```

And again 500 error.
Any idea what should i make at my mysqli prepare so it can be the same as the original query?

Thanks!

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security).

Comment: Using SHA1, MD5 and other weak hashes is garbage security. Mixing it up a little to be "clever" adds zero security, there are cracking programs that will dice this up and churn through thousands of passwords per second without breaking a sweat. **DO IT PROPERLY** and use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). **DO NOT** use home-rolled hashing code like this.

Comment: I'm also really confused why, if you're using OpenCart, you need to go and write your own login layer. Can you explain?

Comment: @tadman it's the opencart default password security, i can't do anything about it. The database is already filled up with users and passwords like this.

Comment: @tadman could you explain how could i use their own functions?

Comment: I'd look through the [OpenCart documentation](http://docs.opencart.com) to see what API methods are exposed. It looks pretty feature complete so there's no reason to chainsaw in your own code like this.

Comment: You don't need to use placeholder for the MySQL function portion, just for the user data, ie `$password`.

Comment: @tadman their login functions returns just true or false, not the hole object as i would like to do in my case. Also updating the version is not possible, cause the project is already in production and i'm only making an api for an app.

Comment: `$this->db->` implies the use of a class/method and I see `$result = mysqli_prepare($db,` - one of those is failing you here. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for the php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php on the query.

Comment: Presumably if you're successfully logged in there's a way of getting the current user, and from there, all the data you need. It's just a case of using the right API calls.

Comment: @tadman I don't think it would be possible from an iOS app to get that data without returning a response.

Comment: Before you go down this path of hacking away at the `mysqli` level, look through the API. Your real question here is "How do I get user data from OpenCart given only their username and password?"

Comment: @tadman nope. The question is, how can i make as an mysqli parameter the password from the first query `(password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "'))))) `

Comment: Use `?` to represent user-data, then `bind_param` to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this should work:

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$result = mysqli_prepare($db, "
    SELECT customer_id, firstname, lastname, email, telephone, fax, address_id, customer_group_id
    FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer`
    WHERE LOWER(email) = ?
    AND password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(?)))))
");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, 'ss', $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $customer_id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone, $fax, $address_id, $customer_group_id);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)) {     
    $id = $customer_id;
    $name = $firstname;
    $surname = $lastname;
    $email = $email;
    $phone = $telephone;
    $fax = $fax;
    $addressid = $address_id;
    $customergroup = $customer_group_id;
}
mysqli_stmt_close($result);
mysqli_close($db);
```

The `md5` option in the original query is strictly there for supporting legacy data and is no longer used by Opencart for password storage so unless you are dealing with table over a decade old, you can do away with that part altogether. Also note, you shouldn't really need to escape the password since 1st order sql injection is already handled by the prepared statement, so should be safe to just pass the raw `$password` parameter to the statement.

Also as noted in the comments, there are already class methods for getting the data you seem to be after.  For example, once a customer is logged in, you can call in any controller:

```
$lastname = $this->customer->getLastName();
$fax = $this->customer->getFax();
```

So if all your after is access to class properties, it may be helpful to know that there are already methods for this.

Comment: I've tried your example, but still it doen't work. I get 500 error.

Comment: if you're getting error 500 it's a server level problem and has to do with something else in your code.

Comment: I think the issue is this one `SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(?))))`

Comment: other API functions/files are working without error. Only this one and i've copy pasted your example since you don't have any mistakes in yours!

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios - You've got syntax errors in your code.  I just corrected three of them and updated my question with the ***exact*** code I just tested on a live installation and it worked fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136105/discussion-between-kwnstantinos-natsios-and-billynoah).